# how to stop scrolling full body in model and only description should scroll. native base Model

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

In this have one input field and belong have description section, still it scrolling whole body but what i'm trying to do, if i scroll body the input should stuck in there but description should be scrollable.

```
<Modal isOpen={true} onClose={true} size={'xl'}>
    <Modal.Content maxH="500">
      {/* <Modal.CloseButton /> */}
      <Modal.Header>
        <Text textAlign={'center'}>Assigned To Picker</Text>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <View height={100}>
          <HStack flex={1} justifyContent="center">
            <View width={"100%"}>
              <TextInput
                mode="flat"
                label="Email"
                activeUnderlineColor="orange"
                underlineColor="gray"
                backgroundColor="white"
                textColor="black"
                borderRadius={2}
              />
            </View>
          </HStack>
        </View>
        <ScrollView flex={1}>
          <Text>
            Create a 'Return Request' under “My Orders” section of
            App/Website. Follow the screens that come up after tapping on
            the 'Return’ button. Please make a note of the Return ID that we
            genetruerate at the end of the process. Keep the item ready for pick
            up or ship it to us basis on the return mod
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button.Group space={2}>
          <Button variant="ghost" colorScheme="blueGray" onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(false);
          }}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(false);
          }}>
            Save
          </Button>
        </Button.Group>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal.Content>
  </Modal>
```

hope you got my point

Comment: `overflow:scroll` should do the work i guess